# Keras-Tuner RuntimeError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-tuner

I'm getting following error and I'm not able to figure out why:

> RuntimeError: Model-building function did not return a valid Keras Model instance, found (<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f74d8b849d0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f74d8b80810>)

I have read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602434/keras-tuner-model-building-function-did-not-return-a-valid-keras-model-instanc/62369789) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/141) which seem to telling to import `keras` from `tensorflow` instead of stand alone `keras` which I'm doing but still getting the error. I would very much appreciate your help in figuring this out. Below is my entire code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Concatenate, Lambda, GaussianNoise, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from numba import njit
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection._split import _BaseKFold, indexable, _num_samples
from sklearn.utils.validation import _deprecate_positional_args
import pandas as pd
import kerastuner as kt
import gc
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import choices
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

class MyTuner(kt.Tuner):
    def run_trial(self, trial, x, y):
        cv = PurgedGroupTimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5, group_gap = 20)
        val_losses = []
        
        for train_indices, test_indices in cv.split(x, groups=x[0]):
            x_train, y_train = x[train_indices, 1:], y[train_indices]
            x_test, y_test = x[test_indices, 1:], y[test_indices]
            
            x_train = apply_transformation(x_train)
            x_test = apply_transformation(x_test)
            
            model = self.hypermodel.build(trial.hyperparameters)
            model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = hp.Int('batch_size', 500, 5000, step=500, default=4000),
                      epochs = hp.Int('epochs', 100, 1000, step=200, default=500))
            
            val_losses.append(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
            
        self.oracle.update_trial(trial.trial_id, {'val_loss': np.mean(val_losses)})
        self.save_model(trial.trial_id, model)

def create_autoencoder(hp, input_dim, output_dim):
    i = Input(input_dim)
    encoded = BatchNormalization()(i)
    encoded = GaussianNoise(hp.Float('gaussian_noise', 1e-2, 1, sampling='log', default=5e-2))(encoded)
    encoded = Dense(hp.Int('encoder_dense', 100, 300, step=50, default=64), activation='relu')(encoded)
    decoded = Dropout(hp.Float('decoder_dropout_1', 1e-1, 1, sampling='log', default=0.2))(encoded)
    decoded = Dense(input_dim,name='decoded')(decoded)
    x = Dense(hp.Int('output_x', 32, 100, step=10, default=32),activation='relu')(decoded)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(hp.Float('x_dropout_1', 1e-1, 1, sampling='log', default=0.2))(x)
    x = Dense(hp.Int('output_x', 32, 100, step=10, default=32),activation='relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(hp.Float('x_dropout_2', 1e-1, 1, sampling='log', default=0.2))(x)    
    x = Dense(output_dim,activation='sigmoid',name='label_output')(x)
    
    encoder = Model(inputs=i,outputs=encoded)
    autoencoder = Model(inputs=i,outputs=[decoded, x])
    
#     optimizer = hp.Choice('optimizer', ['adam', 'sgd'])
    
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=Adam(hp.Float('lr', 0.00001, 0.1, default=0.001)), 
                        loss='sparse_binary_crossentropy',
                        metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return autoencoder, encoder


build_model = lambda hp: create_autoencoder(hp, X[:, 1:].shape[1], y.shape[1])

tuner = MyTuner(
            oracle=kt.oracles.BayesianOptimization(
                    objective=kt.Objective('val_loss', 'min'),
                    max_trials=20),
            hypermodel=build_model,
            directory='./',
            project_name='autoencoders')
    
tuner.search(X, (X,y), callbacks=[EarlyStopping('val_loss',patience=5),
                                  ReduceLROnPlateau('val_loss',patience=3)])

encoder_hp  = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(1)[0]
print("Best Encoder Hyper-parameter:", encoder_hp)

best_autoencoder = tuner.get_best_models(1)[0]
```

Comment: How to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RuntimeError: Model-building function did not return a valid Keras Model instance, found (<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f74d8b849d0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f74d8b80810>)

`(<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f74d8b849d0>, <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f74d8b80810>)`

As you can see this a tuple of two Keras Model instance. This is output of `create_autoencoder(hp, input_dim, output_dim)`.

```py
def create_autoencoder(hp, input_dim, output_dim): 
    # some lines of codes
    return autoencoder, encoder
```

From my understanding, you are not using `encoder`. Therefore, you can remove it in your function.

That function will be look like this

```py
def create_autoencoder(hp, input_dim, output_dim): 
    # some lines of codes
    return autoencoder
```

It will only return **a** Keras Model Instance.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. Is there a way to hyper-parameter search for both autoencoder and encoder using the function `create_autoencoder`. Is it just the matter of compiling `encoder.compile(..)` along with `autoencoder`?

Comment: I think I can't answer your question. You should ask someone else. Sorry mate.

Comment: No worries mate! Thank you for catching that mistake though